# Java App - measure code visited during integration testing

Tags: java, code-coverage

I was wondering is there any tool I can use to instrument my code so that when I perform functional/integration testing, i can get a report of hwat percentage of the code was visited?

We use clover already to test our junit code coverage but it would be great if we could also test something from the functional perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net). Once your clases have been instrumented they can log everything while your server/rich client/whatever is running, and on shutdown record everything.

After that, you can run cobertura report which gives you an html page with full coverage.

Answer (score 2):

If you already use clover, then you could run your app with the instrumented classes and clover will continue to report out what the coverage is.  We've used it to run both unit tests and integration tests, and get the final result at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Or just use IntelliJ.  It'll calculate code coverage every time you run your unit tests if you ask it to.